# How to change the way to get token on OAuth Authentication c# .net core 3.1

Tags: c#, .net-core, oauth-2.0

In my company they recently have changed the way to get the OAuth token, they implemented a step that decrypts a new client's secret which they send to us on the server side. In this step, I need to execute a method called GetValidAuthorizationTokenByAuthorizationCode, where I send "Client ID", "Authorization Code" and redirect Uri:

dynamic token = tokenGenerator.GetValidAuthorizationTokenByAuthorizationCode(client_id, authorizationCode, redirectUri);

But the way I created it, the "authorization_code" was "hide", and I can't find a way to use my custom method.

Here is my ConfigureServices implementation:

````
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDataProtection();
            services.AddSingleton(Configuration);
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            services.Configure<FormOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.ValueCountLimit = int.MaxValue;
                options.ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
            });

            services.AddAuthentication(a =>
                       {
                           a.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                           a.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                           a.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                       })
                       .AddCookie()
                       .AddOAuth("Auth0", options =>
                       {
                           // Configure the Auth0 Client ID and Client Secret
                           options.ClientId = Configuration["Auth0:ClientId"];
                           options.ClientSecret = Configuration["Auth0:ClientSecret"];

                           // Set the callback path
                           // Also ensure that you have added the URL as an Allowed Callback URL in your Auth0 dashboard
                           options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/Home/Login");

                           // Configure the Auth0 endpoints
                           options.AuthorizationEndpoint = $"https://{Configuration["Auth0:Domain"]}/authorize";
                           options.TokenEndpoint = $"https://{Configuration["Auth0:Domain"]}/token";
                           options.UserInformationEndpoint = $"https://{Configuration["Auth0:Domain"]}/tokeninfo";

                           // To save the tokens to the Authentication Properties we need to set this to true
                           // See code in OnTicketReceived event below to extract the tokens and save them as Claims
                           options.SaveTokens = true;

                           // Set scope to openid. See https://auth0.com/docs/scopes
                           options.Scope.Clear();
                           options.Scope.Add("openid");

                           options.Events = new OAuthEvents
                           {
                               // When creating a ticket we need to manually make the call to the User Info endpoint to retrieve the user's information,
                               // and subsequently extract the user's ID and email adddress and store them as claims
                               OnCreatingTicket = async context =>
                              {
                                  // Retrieve user info
                                  var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, context.Options.UserInformationEndpoint);
                                  request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", context.AccessToken);
                                  request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                                  var response = await context.Backchannel.SendAsync(request, context.HttpContext.RequestAborted);
                                  response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                                  // Extract the user info object
                                  var jsonResposta = JObject.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
                                  var funcional = jsonResposta.SelectToken("jwt_token.usr").ToString();

                                  //nome
                                   var nome = jsonResposta.Value<string>("user_id");
                                  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nome))
                                  {
                                      context.Identity.AddClaim(new (ClaimsIdentity.DefaultNameClaimType, nome, ClaimValueTypes.String, context.Options.ClaimsIssuer));
                                  }

                                  // Funcional
                                  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(funcional))
                                  {
                                      context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, funcional, ClaimValueTypes.String, context.Options.ClaimsIssuer));
                                  }
                              }
                           };
                       });
            ;

            services.Configure<FormOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.ValueCountLimit = int.MaxValue;
                options.ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
            });

            services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
            
            services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

            services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                // Timeout de 12 horas
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(43200);
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                // Make the session cookie essential
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            });

            services.AddSingleton(Configuration);
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddControllers()
            .AddJsonOptions(opts => opts.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null);

        } ```
````

Is there any way to get the authorization code to customize the way of the middleware get the token?

I'm using Web MVC application with `.net core 3.1.`

Thanks :D

Comment: Seems a bit weird your company decided to create an extra pretty much pointless step in the OAuth Spec.  Why encrypt the client secret, What are you going to use to encrypt it, What ever you use to encrypt it won't be secure.

Answer (score 0):

i finally solve this by doing manually the stepts that was done by middleware, and storage the token on cookie.